# Why is my MEF usage not CLS-compliant?

Tags: silverlight, warnings, cls-compliant

When I compile my Silverlight application, all of the elements that are decorated with MEF attributes are warning of CLS-noncompliance. When I compile again, the warnings do not return, and my application seems to run fine. Is this something that I need to worry about?  I'm using a standard naming convention for properties, classes, and such.  The only time I use underscores is with private members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume the assembly the MEF attributes were contained in do not have the CLSCompliant attribute set.

IE, if you reference a Silverlight class library, the class library should have this attribute set in its AssemblyInfo file:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```